# In SQL Server 2008, constraints are not working even though I already added following query

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server 2008, constraints are not working even though I already added the following query

```
ALTER TABLE [CONSTITUTIONSMSTTEMP] 
  ADD CONSTRAINT CHK_DiscardDate_Reason  
     CHECK (Discardreason  NOT IN ('!','@','$','%')
            --like '%[^a-zA-Z0-9]%'  
            OR Discardreason IS NULL);
```

Comment: Can you please share more code? means which statements are not following this constraints?

Comment: It works exactly as expected for me - [Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6abf0/1).

Comment: It is looking fine. Show your insert script!!

Comment: Define "*not working*"

Comment: @GarethD,please check this. EXECUTE dbo.InsertT 'sdf!@'; Even I inserted special characters like ! and @ at the end of string. and after execution record is inserted.... even though check constraints are added on it..?

Comment: Show the table definition and procedure definition as well. You need `NOT LIKE` if you are trying to prevent strings containing those characters.

Comment: As @MartinSmith has said, you need `NOT LIKE` - Also the NULL check is redundant. You want something like `Discardreason  not LIKE ('%[!@$\%]%') ESCAPE ('\')` - [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/32e93/1)

Comment: @MartinSmith  , Thanks Martin, query Worked Fine

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
ALTER TABLE [CONSTITUTIONSMSTTEMP]
  ADD CONSTRAINT CHK_DiscardDate_Reason CHECK ( Discardreason NOT LIKE '%[!|@|$|%]%'
```

);

Comment: `OR Discardreason IS NULL` is unnecessary in check constraints. If the expression evaluates to unknown the check is passed. This won't work correctly though. `!-@` will be interpreted as a range not a set. And same for `$-%`. Why have you added the `-`?

Comment: @MartinSmith , Please give me any (query) example that restricts special characters...